# Jordan–Chevalley decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

I'm trying to understand the proof of it in Humphreys(Humphreys 1972, Prop. 4.2, p. 17). And I've not got over which field we are working. The characteristic polynomial may not have roots in the initial field, but he considers the endomorphisms of kind $ (x - a_i * id) $, where x is the endomorphism that we want to decompose, and $a_i$ is one of its roots.

Comment: Humphreys has written more than one book. Perhaps you could mention the title?

Comment: Humphreys, James E. (1972), Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory

Answer (score 1):

The first paragraph of Chapter II of Humphreys' book (pg. 15) states the assumption that the field $F$ is algebraically closed and has characteristic 0 for the duration of the book. Hence the roots of the characteristic polynomial must be contained in $F$.